# Save image to a one to one relationship with a core data string

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, segue, one-to-one

My code below should follow the diagram below. It features a tableview where it stores a user generated string. Using core data entity Item attribute tbox. Then when the selects a tableview cell it segues the string into another class which features a label and imageview. The user should be able choose a photo from the photo gallery and then save to core data Entity Pic attriubte pic. Anytime the user selects a name from the tableview cell if and only if  a image is saved within it should always match the name from the table view cell. This is the link to GitHub https://github.com/redrock34/tableviewcell-relationship-between-text-and-string/blob/master/michaelVick.xcodeproj.zip.

[image]

```
import UIKit;import CoreData

 class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemName.count
    }



    var itemName : [NSManagedObject] = []
    var txtField = UITextField()
    var btn = UIButton()
    var theField = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        [txtField,btn,theField].forEach({
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })
        txtField.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-100, y: view.center.y-250, width: 200, height: 40)
        txtField.placeholder = "Enter Name"
        txtField.textAlignment = .center
        txtField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-100, y: view.center.y-200, width: 200, height: 40)
        theField.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-100, y: view.center.y-150, width: 200, height: 250)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn.setTitle("Add Name", for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(save), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        theField.dataSource = self
        theField.delegate = self
        loadData()
        theField.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    }

    @objc func save() {
        let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext


        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: context)


        let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        theTitle.setValue(txtField.text, forKey: "tbox")



        do {
            try context.save()
            itemName.append(theTitle)

        }
        catch {
            print("d")
        }
        txtField.text = ""
        self.theField.reloadData()

    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
        let cell = theField.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for : indexPath)

        cell.selectionStyle = .default
        let attr1 = title.value(forKey: "name") as? String



        let text = [attr1].flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(text)"

        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero




        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero



        return cell

    }

    func loadData() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "tbox")
        do {
            self.itemName = try managedContext.fetch(fetch)
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not load. \(error)")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let cell = theField.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        let vc = fullScreen()
        vc.tim = (cell?.textLabel!.text)!

        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        self.present(vc, animated: true)

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            let appd = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appd.persistentContainer.viewContext

            context.delete(itemName[indexPath.row])
            itemName.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {
                print("d")
            }
            self.theField.reloadData()

        }
    }




}




    class fullScreen : UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{



        var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

        @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
            if let error = error {
                // we got back an error!
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
            } else {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }


        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
            guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
                fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
            }

            // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.

            txt.image = selectedImage

            // Dismiss the picker.
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    var tim = ""
    var cook = UILabel()
            var add = UIButton()
    var back = UIButton()
    var txt = UIImageView()
    var itemName : [NSManagedObject] = []
    var itemName2 : [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal

        [cook,back,txt,add].forEach({
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })
        back.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
        txt.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        cook.text = tim
        cook.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y-200, width: 60, height: 30)
        back.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y-100, width: 30, height: 30)
         add.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x+115, y: view.center.y-100, width: 30, height: 30)
        txt.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y-0, width: 100, height: 50)
        back.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
          add.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ad), for: .touchUpInside)
        loadData()

    }


    @objc func moveRight() {

        save()

        let vc = ViewController()

        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

        self.present(vc, animated: true)

            }
        @objc func ad() {

     imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
           imagePicker.delegate = self
           imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
           present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

    @objc func save() {
        let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: context)
        let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        theTitle.setValue(txt.image, forKey: "tbox")



        do {
            try context.save()
            itemName.append(theTitle)

        }catch{}





    }

    func loadData() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "tbox")
        do {
            self.itemName2 = try managedContext.fetch(fetch)


        }
        catch {
            print("Could not load. \(error)")
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: ... and the problem is ....?

Comment: I don't know how to get my code to do what I am showing in the photo I posted.